# SQL select with conditions and without duplicates

Tags: sql, database, select, group-by, datatables

I'm trying to create SQL query to get specific entities with some conditions. The thing is I have some duplicate entities I want to avoid. 
My data table (the table represent drivers) is: 
[image]

I want to get some drivers with condition of specific facility ID/parkinglot ID.
For example, in case I want all the drivers at facility with ID '2', I want to get:

```
11112 Michael Smith
```

and not:

```
11112 Michael Smith
11112 Michael Smith
```

I want the same thing will happen with the parkinglot ID and with the facility Id together.

I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM "DRIVERS" 
where facilityid = '2'
group by driverid
```

And I got an error:

```
Could not execute 'SELECT * FROM "DRIVERS" where facilityid = '2' group by driverid'
invalid column name: The column 'DRIVERS.FIRSTNAME' is invalid in the select list because the GROUP BY clause or an aggregation function does not contain it: line 1 col 8 (at pos 7)
```

Any ideas?
Thank you!

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Comment: dont use `select *` and `group by`

Comment: Do `SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2, ...` instead.

Comment: in MySQL it would work

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to get the distinct values from the table then do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM "DRIVERS"
WHERE facilityid = '2';
```

`GROUP BY` should be used when you are aggregating data

Edit:
To get the results you asked for you could use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DRIVERID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME
FROM "DRIVERS"
WHERE facilityid = '2';
```

Comment: Note that OP doesn't want that result.

Answer (score 0):

YOU WILL GET THE RESULT WITH THIS QUERY.
select distinct(DRIVERID),FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME FROM "DRIVERS" where facilityid = '2'.

Comment: This will work but fyi: `DISTINCT` is a modifier not a function, it will apply to all the columns selected.  Parentheses `()` will have no effect.

Comment: DISTINCT(column) - gives you the result according to the values present in the column specified in the DISTINCT because you are performing the distinct operation only on one column. if distinct apply to all column then there is no meaning to pass the column in DISTINCT().

Comment: Your last sentence is exactly correct, `DISTINCT()` isn't a thing.  `SELECT DISTINCT (A), B, C` is the same as `SELECT DISTINCT A, B, C`.  Putting a column in `()` won't cause the query to fail, it just won't do anything.  You can put all your columns in `()` and it won't change anything either: `SELECT DISTINCT (A), (B), (C)`